# Running discord bot on Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I recently got a RPi3B for my birthday and I just made my own C# discord bot using Discord.Net I created some commands and figured it'd be cool to run it on my RPi so I don't have to have my laptop on all the time, so I uploaded my bot to bitbucket and cloned it onto my RPi (on raspbian btw) I can program a little, but I really do not know what mono and .Net core etc are used for, but I read I needed mono to run a C# program, so I installed this on my RPi, so my project.exe would run, but it keeps on disconnecting (it runs just fine on my laptop).

[Here](https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net/issues/703) I found someone with the same problem, but I couldn't figure out what I should try now, I've tried installing .Net core 2 in many shady ways, but the walkthroughs I tried didn't seem to work

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's hard to tell with just a general description of your project - does it just disconnect or does the program stop? You could start diagnosing the problem by logging exceptions and the general "flow" of the program. Once you have a bit more information about the problem, add relevant code to the question if you can.

Comment: It's just like the link I put in, it just keeps on connecting and disconnecting straight afterwards.
But someone said:
"1.0 doesn't work with mono, you should try with .Net Core 2.0"
And the problem isn't with my code, it just won't work with mono (as far as I know). 
I believe it's something like Raspbian not being compatible with .Net Core 2.0 or so

Comment: The Discord.Net libary was made for the core version of .Net so there is no guarantee that it will work with mono